# Is it possible to make database owner read only?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

The database owner can revoke certain privileges from themselves such as INSERT but is it possible to revoke further privileges such as DROP for read-only operation?

Comment: Why not create a user with only SELECT privileges and use that?

Comment: It would be better to just create a separate group with only Read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The privilege to DROP an object does not exist as such and thus can't be revoked. Owning an object implies the right to drop it, and having the right to drop an object implies owning it. Here's a relevant excerpt from [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)'s documentation, which is pretty explicit about this point:

> The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is
>   not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and
>   cannot be granted or revoked. (However, a similar effect can be
>   obtained by granting or revoking membership in the role that owns the
>   object; see below.) The owner implicitly has all grant options for the
>   object, too.